# Can't get button to show up on click with javascript visibility

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having trouble working with my next button on my webpage. I can get the other parts of the page (the answer message) to show up fine with when the button is clicked, but for some reason it will not work with this next button. Hiding it works fine, but when I click the button the next button will not show up. If I don't hide or style = "none", the button shows up fine. I've tried `.style = "none"` & `.style = "block"` and `.visibility = "hidden"` and `.visibility = "visible"`, with no success. If anyone could give me some insight I'd appreciate it!

```js
document.getElementById("correct").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("score").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("value").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("next").style.visibility = "hidden";

function clicky() {
  var user_answer = document.getElementById("user_answer").value;
  var correct = document.getElementById("correct").innerHTML;
  var score = document.getElementById("score").innerHTML;
  var value = document.getElementById("value").innerHTML;
  var val2 = value.substring(1);
  var worth = parseInt(val2);
  if (user_answer == correct) {
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "Correct!";
    score += worth;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "Sorry, the answer is actually " + correct + " not " + user_answer;
    score -= worth;
  }
  document.getElementById("showed_score").innerHTML = "Score is now $" + score;
  document.getElementById("score_get").value = score;
  document.getElementById("next").style.visibility = "visible";
};

function next() {

};
```

```html
<div class="user-response">
  What is <input type="text" id="user_answer"> ?
  <button onclick="clicky()" type=b utton>Submit</button>
  <button onclick="next()" type=s ubmit id="next">Next -></button>
</div>

<p id="correct">{{clue.answer}}</p>
<p id="score">{{score}}</p>
<p id="value">{{clue.worth}}</p>
<form method="GET">
  <input type="hidden" name="score_get" value=0>
</form>

<div class="answer" id="answer">
</div>
```

Comment: Check your browser console for errors.

Comment: Put an answer below that actually renders something upon submitting a value. Using math.floor to convert to number or atleast make sure it's a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created this interactive snippet. Looks like there is an error (`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null`) happening right above that is throwing console errors. Based on your code the elements `showed_score` and `score_get` do not exist. Fixing this will hopefully fix your original problem.

```
document.getElementById("showed_score").innerHTML = "Score is now $" + score;
document.getElementById("score_get").value = score;
document.getElementById("next").style.visibility = "visible";
```

```html
  <div class = "user-response">
        What is <input type = "text" id = "user_answer"> ?
        <button onclick = "clicky()" type = button>Submit</button>
        <button onclick = "next()" type = submit id = "next">Next -></button>
    </div>

    <p id = "correct"></p>
    <p id = "score"></p>
    <p id = "value"></p>
    <form method = "GET">
        <input type = "hidden" name = "score_get" value = 0>
    </form>

    <div class = "answer" id = "answer">
    </div>

    <script type = "text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("correct").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("score").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("value").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("next").style.visibility = "hidden";
    function clicky(){
        var user_answer = document.getElementById("user_answer").value;
        var correct = document.getElementById("correct").innerHTML;
        var score = document.getElementById("score").innerHTML;
        var value = document.getElementById("value").innerHTML;
        var val2 = value.substring(1);
        var worth = parseInt(val2);
        if (user_answer == correct) {
            document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "Correct!";
            score += worth;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "Sorry, the answer is actually " + correct + " not " + user_answer;
            score -= worth;
        }
        document.getElementById("showed_score").innerHTML = "Score is now $" + score;
        document.getElementById("score_get").value = score;
        document.getElementById("next").style.visibility = "visible";
    };

    function next(){

    };
    </script>
```

Comment: This was it! I had done name = "score_get" instead of id. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the clicky function you are trying to set the innerHTML of a missing element "showed_score", It results with an error and quit the function before it is done.

Just remove this line or add the element to your html

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what template engine youre using to render {{clue.answer}} but I imagine there's an answer in there somewhere.  Try the following code instead (you were missing an id reference for getElementById :

```
<div class = "user-response">
    What is <input type = "text" id = "user_answer"> ?
    <button onclick = "clicky()" type = button>Submit</button>
    <button onclick = "next()" type = submit id = "next">Next -></button>
</div>

<p id = "correct">{{clue.answer}}</p>
<p id = "score">{{score}}</p>
<p id = "value">{{clue.worth}}</p>
<form method = "GET">
    <input type = "hidden" name = "score_get"  id="score_get" value = 0>
</form>

<div class = "answer" id = "answer">
</div>

<div id="showed_score">

</div>

<script type = "text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("correct").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("score").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("value").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("next").style.visibility = "hidden";
    function clicky(){
        var user_answer = document.getElementById("user_answer").value;
        var correct = document.getElementById("correct").innerHTML;
        var score = document.getElementById("score").innerHTML;
        var value = document.getElementById("value").innerHTML;
        var val2 = value.substring(1);
        var worth = parseInt(val2);
        if (user_answer == correct) {
            document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "Correct!";
            score += worth;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "Sorry, the answer is actually " + correct + " not " + user_answer;
            score -= worth;
        }
        document.getElementById("showed_score").innerHTML = "Score is now $" + Math.floor(score);
        document.getElementById("score_get").value = score;
        document.getElementById("next").style.visibility = "visible";
    }

    function next(){

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try commenting these 2 lines:

```
document.getElementById("showed_score").innerHTML = "Score is now $" + score;
document.getElementById("score_get").value = score;
```

They trigger an error which prevents the button from becoming visible.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You probably have an error before it gets to the code for visibility.

Look in your console to find errors and what is causing it.

Here's your example with most of it commented out and it works:

```js
    document.getElementById("correct").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("score").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("value").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("next").style.visibility = "hidden";
    function clicky(){
        var user_answer = document.getElementById("user_answer").value;
        //var correct = document.getElementById("correct").innerHTML;
        //var score = document.getElementById("score").innerHTML;
        //var value = document.getElementById("value").innerHTML;
        //var val2 = value.substring(1);
        //var worth = parseInt(val2);
        if (user_answer == correct) {
            document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "Correct!";
            score += worth;
        }
        else {
            //document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "Sorry, the answer is actually " + correct + " not " + user_answer;
            //score -= worth;
        }
        //document.getElementById("showed_score").innerHTML = "Score is now $" + score;
        //document.getElementById("score_get").value = score;
        document.getElementById("next").style.visibility = "visible";
    };

    function next(){

    };
```

```html
 <div class = "user-response">
    What is <input type = "text" id = "user_answer"> ?
    <button onclick = "clicky()" type = button>Submit</button>
    <button onclick = "next()" type = submit id="next">Next -></button>
</div>

<p id = "correct">{{clue.answer}}</p>
<p id = "score">{{score}}</p>
<p id = "value">{{clue.worth}}</p>

<form method = "GET">
    <input type = "hidden" name = "score_get" value = 0>
</form>

<div class = "answer" id = "answer">
</div>
```